# How to filter temporary table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a stored procedure and store the columns in a temporary table called `@Temp`. I want to filter the `@Temp` temporary table now based on the value in column.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @ActivityId INT
    DECLARE @NM AS DATE
    DECLARE @Tmp VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @Temp AS TABLE (
        MachineName VARCHAR(500)
        ,ActivityName VARCHAR(500)
        ,NM DATE
        )

    DECLARE Temcur1 CURSOR
    FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT ActivityId
            ,MachineId
            ,[NextMaintenance] = dbo.udf_GetDateOnFrequency(CreatedOn, Frequency, Frequency_Unit)
        FROM activity_master
        WHERE Frequency_Unit > 0
            AND (
                Frequency <> ''
                OR Frequency <> '&nbsp;'
                )
        ) T
    WHERE [NextMaintenance] >= cast(@StartDate AS DATE)
        AND [NextMaintenance] <= cast(@EndDate AS DATE)

    OPEN Temcur1

    FETCH Temcur1
    INTO @ActivityId
        ,@machineID
        ,@NM

    WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE Temp1 CURSOR
        FOR
        SELECT Item
        FROM dbo.udf_cmn_split(@MachineId, ',')

        OPEN Temp1

        FETCH Temp1
        INTO @Tmp

        WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @Temp
            SELECT [m] = (
                    SELECT Machine_Name
                    FROM machine_master
                    WHERE machine_Id = @Tmp
                    )
                ,[a] = (
                    SELECT ActivityName
                    FROM activity_master
                    WHERE Activityid = @ActivityId
                    )
                ,@NM

            FETCH Temp1
            INTO @Tmp
        END

        CLOSE Temp1

        DEALLOCATE Temp1

        FETCH Temcur1
        INTO @ActivityId
            ,@machineID
            ,@NM
    END

    CLOSE Temcur1

    DEALLOCATE Temcur1

    --select Machine_Name, am.ActivityName,Replace(Convert(varchar,CAST(NextMaintenanceDate As date),106),' ','-')[NM] from Maintenance_Activity m inner join Machine_Master mm on m.MachineId = mm.Machine_Id 
    --inner join Activity_Master am on m.ActivityId=am.ActivityId where Completed_Status='PENDING'
    --and [NextMaintenanceDate]>cast(getdate()-7 as date)
    --and [NextMaintenanceDate]<cast(getdate()+7 as date)
    --Union  
    SELECT MachineName
        ,ActivityName
        ,Replace(Convert(VARCHAR, CAST(NM AS DATE), 106), ' ', '-') NM
    FROM @Temp
    WHERE MachineName = @MachineID
END
```

In the above code i can select values with

```
SELECT MachineName
,ActivityName
,Replace(Convert(VARCHAR, CAST(NM AS DATE), 106), ' ', '-') NM
FROM @Temp
```

but if I give where condition

```
SELECT MachineName
,ActivityName
,Replace(Convert(VARCHAR, CAST(NM AS DATE), 106), ' ', '-') NM
FROM @Temp
WHERE MachineName = @MachineID
```

it is not returning any columns.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest adding print statements to verify MachineName can potentially match MachineID.  Typically an ID is an number, and a name is character data.

Comment: Do the values in `activity_master.MachineId` (i.e. those being placed into `@MachineID` definitely match those in `machine_master.Machine_Name` (i.e. those being written to `@Temp.MachineName`?

Comment: I have declared MachineID as string and i am passing the Machine name for the same.

Comment: Did you add print statements to verify?  If the only thing that you add is the where clause and you then don't get any records, you have your answer.

Comment: _"In the above code i can select values with"_ - so select all the values and also select this `SELECT Item FROM dbo.udf_cmn_split(@MachineId, ',')`. Take a look at both. After that - add print command to your script to debug and check each `MachineID` value. Could be your splitting functions is out of order.